# How do I script with R15?

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make the game with R15, but I don't know how to script with it. For example: if I wanted to pick up a item, it will pick it up when I press a key or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference R15 would make in scripting is if you used CFrame Animations for your characters. If this is what's bothering you, then I **HIGHLY** recommend that you switch to ROBLOX's animation editor system. It is much more efficient, and easier to script. If it is something else, then perhaps you've made a mistake in your code.